# Is there a multi-key key-value store?

Tags: database, data-warehouse, key-value-store

Is there a specialized store for storing tuples i.e. t=(clicks, impressions, ctr) hashed on multiple values - let's say pageId, categoryId, userId, sessionId et cetera.

I know I could do this using MySQL, MongoDb et cetera. But I am more looking for some specialized and mabye even embedded (in Java) store. It does not need to offer a complex query language or transactions like RDMBS. But atomicity and durability would be a pro. ;)

I figure this could also be of use for DWH-type applications storing aggregate data in multiple dimensions but I have not found any such product.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bets are to either to use

```
HashMap<Key1Type, HashMap<Key2Type, ValueType>>
```

or if your items can all be represented via string, you could concatenate their values and store them all in

```
HashMap<string, ValueType>
```

Comment: Ok, I know how to do that... but I am asking about a "store" meaning Memcached for multi-keys.

Comment: There was another thread about how to do this in Java. In fact I thought about using something like Terracotta and building this kind of datastructure.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood.  I don't know of anything along those lines, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with a periodic load process an OLAP server such as Mondrian or SQL Server Analysis Services might work for you.  They do exactly this sort of thing, although the underlying data structure is not a hash table.  Practically you will need to stage the data into a database and load the data from the database into the cube.

Comment: Yeah, well I need this to drive an algorithm and I think Pentaho does not meet the required performance for very fast key/value look-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Using a key-value store you can  always use key composition to store multiple columns in single key column. That's said [wiredtiger](http://source.wiredtiger.com) does offer multiple columns on key and value with the ability to do projection to build indices.

Key composition is the pratice of packing a multiple value in single value the simplest composition use a char as separator such as `":"`.